# Cross domain ajax does not work with redirect in mobile safari

Tags: ajax, redirect, safari, cross-domain, mobile-safari

I'm experiencing this issue that's mentioned in this WebKit bug:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57600

The issue is with mobile Safari, it works with Google Chrome and Firefox. The same code where I redirect a cross domain ajax request works with Google Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't with mobile Safari.

As I understand the bug was filed in WebKit version 525:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57600

And solved in WebKit version 528 (I figured this since a different regression bug was opened on the same issue):
https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2012-April/429252.html

But with my mobile Safari on an iPhone device, the redirect is denied, even though I have mobile Safari with WebKit version 534 (a much later version).

Has anyone experienced this behavior, and is there a solution to this?

Note: I do have the cross domain (CORS) headers defined (since it is working in Google Chrome and Firefox).

Edit: The same issue with Safari for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue with several mobile browsers (`Safari`, `Chrome`/`Dolphi`n on `Android`).

I've no solution for the `302`, but I found a workaround:

- the Java framework we use can either redirect or forward `POST` responses, so we changed it to `forwards` mode.

Using forwards result in a `200`, so the `AJAX` success handler (we use `jQuery`) can retrieve the data properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, in JSP, I can also forward the request, like: getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
        "/JSP/Demo.hello.jsp").forward(request,response); but still I would like to redirect and not forward the request to a JSP page.